# Using CoreData Objects in a List as Environment Object

Tags: core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm currently creating a News-Feed-Reader App with SwiftUI.

I'm fetching the feed-items and storing them in CoreData

I'd like to display the objects in a List containing NavigationLinks to a Detail View and automatically mark them as read when clicking on them.

I'm currently fetching the objects and putting them in a ObservableObject.
This is the ObservableObject class:

```
final class FeedItem: ObservableObject, Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: FeedItem, rhs: FeedItem) -> Bool {
        return lhs.item.pubDate == rhs.item.pubDate && lhs.item.articleUrl == rhs.item.articleUrl
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(item.articleUrl)
    }

    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()


    init(item: NewsItem) {
        self.item = item
    }
    // NewsItem is the Managed Object
    var item: NewsItem

    var bookmarked: Bool {
        set {
            //This function fetches the Object and marks it as bookmarked
            DatabaseManager().markAs(item: item, .read, newValue)
            self.item.bookmarked = newValue
        }
        get {
            self.item.bookmarked
        }
    }

    var read: Bool {
        set {
            //This function fetches the Object and marks it as read
            DatabaseManager().markAs(item: item, .read, newValue)
            self.item.read = newValue
        }
        get {
            self.item.read

        }
    }

}
```

In the moment Im creating an environment Object (EO) containing an array of all ObservableObjects
This EO is passed down to the list and whenever Im clicking on an item Im setting its read value to true thereby changing the Core Data Object.

This is the list:

```
@EnvironmentObject var feed: // THe array of ObservableObjects
List() {
    ForEach(feed.items.indices, id:\.self) { i in
        Button(action: {
            self.feed.items[i].read = true
            self.selectedItem = i
            self.showDetail = true
        }) {
            ListFeedItem(item: self.$feed.items[i])
        }
    }
}
```

This method is quite slow. Whenever I'm opening the Detail View and going back a few seconds later the List-Item takes multiple seconds to refresh.

Any ideas on how I could improve this?